# python class with user defined expressions executed at runtime

Tags: python, lambda

I'd like to build a class that is able to take a few user defined expressions at runtime and to calculations based on them and a few predefined variables that the class owns, e.g. the user will know that the variables a,b,c & d exist:

pseudo code:

```
>>> foo = myclass()

>>> foo.a = 2
>>> foo.b = 3
>>> foo.expression = 'a + b'
>>> foo.run_expression()
5

>>> foo.expression = 'a * b'
>>> foo.run_expression()
10
```

I've explored lambda functions but they seems to need me to explicitly define what the inputs are for the lambda function every time I create a new one which would mean a lot of boiler plate input from the user ever time they wanted to update the lambda as I know that the inputs would always be a predefined set of variables.

does anybody have experience doing anything similar, or have any thoughts on how to structure a program like this?

Comment: the good old evil eval()? but the real point is... why do you need something like that??

Comment: but would i even be able to `eval()` with access to the internal variables of the class without doing lots of string manipulation?

Comment: yes. that's why it's called the *evil* eval :D

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval you can pass the context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To evaluate expressions as Python, use the [`eval()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval), passing in `vars(self)` as the namespace:

```
def run_expression(self):
    return eval(self.expression, vars(self))
```

Do know this opens you up to attack vectors, where malicious users can execute arbitrary code and change your program to do completely different things.

Demo:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def run_expression(self):
...         return eval(self.expression, vars(self))
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.a = 2
>>> f.b = 3
>>> f.expression = 'a + b'
>>> f.run_expression()
5
```

Comment: thats great thanks, in this case there shouldn't be any trouble with malicious attacks, no personal information is there and all they will be able to do is crash their own program :)